# Apple Map : get direction

Tags: iphone, dictionary

How can I use Apple map for getting direction between two places?
I can provide the latitude and longitude of that two places?
Is it possible to show the direction in my app itself?
or Should I need to show the direction in the in built Map app of apple's iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send user to navigation app in iOS6 or google maps prior to iOS6.

Here's a sample code:

```
        Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
            // iOS 6 MKMapItem available
            MKPlacemark* place = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:_targetLocation addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem* destination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:place];
            destination.name = @"Name Here!";
            NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: destination, nil];
            NSDictionary* options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving,
                                     MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey, nil];
            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:items launchOptions:options];
        } else {
            // Pre-iOS 6
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = _lastLocation.coordinate;

            NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%g,%g&daddr=%g,%g", coords.latitude, coords.longitude, _targetLocation.latitude, _targetLocation.longitude];
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for showing directions on Apple map. It'll work for current place to your destination place and you just need to pass lat & long of destination place.

```
double destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude;
destinationLatitude=// Latitude of destination place.
destinationLongitude=// Longitude of destination place.

Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)])
        {

            // Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate =
            CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(destinationLatitude,destinationLongitude);
            MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate
                                                           addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
            [mapItem setName:@"Name/text on destination annotation pin"];



            // Set the directions mode to "Driving"
            // Can use MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving instead
            NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving};
            // Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
           MKMapItem *currentLocationMapItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
            // Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
            // Set the direction mode in the launchOptions dictionary
            [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[currentLocationMapItem, mapItem]
                           launchOptions:launchOptions];
```